# Regex to find a starting pattern including either of 2 strings but not contain a specific text

Tags: regex

I want to use Regex to find a line containing a particular pattern.

The pattern should be a string starting with 2 characters (a-zA-Z0-9) followed by a dash then either "FAL" or "SAL" and does not include the term "OJT" at all.

Just want to make sure I have the right or am I missing something as it doesn't appear to work as expected

```
^[a-zA-z0-9]{1,2}(?=.*?\-SAL|-FAL\b)((?!OJT).)*$
```

Comment: Your regex seems to work fine and you don't need to use tempered greedy token (is expensive so use only when there is no other way), a simple negative look head should be good enough.

Comment: Maybe `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}(?!.*OJT).*?(?:-SAL|-FAL)\b.*$`? See https://regex101.com/r/Q14Ayg/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}(?!.*OJT).*?(?:-SAL|-FAL)\b.*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Q14Ayg/3)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}` - one or two alphanumeric chars
- `(?!.*OJT)` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible, followed with `OJT` char sequence should not appear immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?:-SAL|-FAL)\b` - `-SAL` or `-FAL` not followed with a word char
- `.*` - the rest of string.

See the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z0-9%5D%7B1%2C2%7D(%3F!.*OJT).*%3F(%3F%3A-SAL%7C-FAL)%5Cb.*):

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that, if the -FAL or -SAL were case insensitive is it good enough to just use /i at the end?

Comment: @Alan It depends what the language is. Either `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}(?!.*OJT).*?(?:-SAL|-FAL)\b.*/i` or `(?i)^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,2}(?!.*OJT).*?(?:-SAL|-FAL)\b.*` will do the job in 96% cases.

Comment: Ok thanks at the moment I'm using in excel with VB so I see there's an option for `.IgnoreCase = False` so I presume I just set it to `True`.

Comment: @Alan `pattern.IgnoreCase` must be set to `True` to ignore case.

Comment: Thanks again, still learning the regex. Any good resources you could advise?

Comment: @Alan I do not know your level of regex knowledge, so I can only suggest doing all lessons at [regexone.com](http://regexone.com/), reading through [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), [regex SO tag description](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info) (with many other links to great online resources), and the community SO post called [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). Also, [rexegg.com](http://rexegg.com) is worth having a look at.